# evaluating Lagrange polynomial using recursion in python (recursion limit exceeded)

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following Lagrange polynomial:
[image]

and I am trying to use recursion to solve it, so first I wrote the equation as:

> ((2*n+1)/(n+1)) * x * P(n,x) - (n/(n+1)) * P(n-1,x)

and I wrote the following function:

```
def P(n,x):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return ((2*n+1)/(n+1)) * x * P(n-1,x) - (n/(n+1)) * P(n-1,x)
```

but I got the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\practical work 7\main.py", line 80, in <module>
    print (P(2,2))
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\practical work 7\main.py", line 78, in P
    return ((2*n+1)/n+1) * x * P(n,x) - (n/(n+1)) * P (n-1,x)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\practical work 7\main.py", line 78, in P
    return ((2*n+1)/n+1) * x * P(n,x) - (n/(n+1)) * P (n-1,x)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\practical work 7\main.py", line 78, in P
    return ((2*n+1)/n+1) * x * P(n,x) - (n/(n+1)) * P (n-1,x)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\practical work 7\main.py", line 73, in P
    if n == 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I do not want to increase the number of allowed recursions, unless that is the only way to solve the question

I believe that the equation is wrong, since `P(n,x)` will always call the function and the function will go to the last return again, and it will keep doing that all the time, I just want to know if I missed something or the Question itself is wrong.

Comment: You have to remember that your function takes `n` as a parameter, but in the image shown the function takes `n+1` as a parameter. so you have to substract `1` from every `n` in the image.

Comment: Your code and the error stacktrace do not match up.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk oh yeah, Sorry I did not realize that, I edited it

Comment: @ErikMcKelvey , Thank you, That worked for me, and I understood my mistake, Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def P(n, x):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n == 1:
        return x
    return (2 * n - 1) / n * x * P(n - 1, x) - (n - 1) / n * P(n - 2, x)
```

Examples:

```
>>> P(2,3)
13.0
>>> P(3,3)
63.0
>>> P(4,3)
321.0
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked !!